# Angular mat-datepicker page change events

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I've got an Angular 12 app with an [Angular Material date range picker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api) in it.

I'd like to be able to get notified when the month is changed in the calendar view so that i can asynchronously make a server call and find out which dates are allowed for selection.

I know `mat-date-picker` does offer a `(monthSelected)` output, but that output only fires when you select a month from the multi-month view. If you use the `forward` and `back` buttons when viewing dates in a month, the output doesn't fire.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<!-- template -->

<mat-date-range-picker (monthNavigated)="monthChanged($event)"></mat-date-range-picker>

<!-- component code --> 

async monthChanged(date: Date){
  // we've got the start date for the month in view.
  this.allowedDates = await this.apiService.getAllowedDatesForMonth(date);
}
```

I've got a [Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kub3r8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-range-picker-forms-example.html) with an example working where it notifies us when you select a specific month directly **from multi-month view**.

Is there a way I can get it to tell me when you switch months *when you're already in month view*?